# I have tried to acces the content of the website: http://paraphrase.org/#/search?q=tree&filter=&lang=en

Tags: java

I have tried to acces the content of the following website: http://paraphrase.org/ in order to pass queries, unfortunately I am not getting the content (retrieved answers). I will be very grateful for any help,here is my code;

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class PPdbURL {   
    public static void main(String args[]) throws URISyntaxException{ 
        String nextLine;               
        URL url = null;      
        URLConnection urlConn = null;        
        InputStreamReader  inStream = null;       
        BufferedReader buff = null;       
        try{  // Create the URL obect that points  at the default file index.html                            
            url = new URL("http://paraphrase.org/#/search?q=tree&filter=&lang=en" );                       
            urlConn = url.openConnection();         
            inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());                                  
            buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);  // Read and print the lines from 
            //index.html

            while (true){             
                nextLine =buff.readLine();              
                if (nextLine !=null){                 
                    System.out.println(nextLine);             
                }             
                else{               
                  break;            
                }         
            }      
        } 
        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {        
            System.out.println("Please check the URL:" + e.toString() );                                                       
        } 
        catch(IOException  e1){      
            System.out.println("Can't read  from the Internet: "+  e1.toString() );                                             
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What ARE you getting?  Exception?  Null content?

Comment: I tried to post the out- put, but it was too long. Basically it was just html with but the last indicated elements to do with Java script:                                             <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]--><script src="scripts/b4d2052d.vendor.js"></script><script src="scripts/d62eb2f0.scripts.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

When you say you are not getting the content, do you mean you are not getting the right content? I have tried your code and it works fine i.e I do get an HTTP response.

The thing to recognise it the snippet above is that you cannot use the URL above to make HTTP requests to the server and expect it to behave like the paraphrase web page. This is because of the fragment identifier ('#') in the URL.

RFC 3986 and RFC 1738 both explain that the fragment identifier is not part of the URL or URI when derefencing and everything after the fragment identifier should be removed.

So in the above example, the URL connection is only being made to http://paraphrase.org/

On inspecting the paraphrase web document, the query and search is actually being activated using javascript, on the client, operating on a different URL. A request is made to a endpoint which is returning a JSON resource. The javascript on the client is then parsing and rendering results to the browser.

The URL of this HTTP request is below:

http://paraphrase.org/api/en/search/?batchNumber=0&needsPOSList=true&q=tree

As you can see, this produces the search result data.

So in your example, you should consider using the same URL but instead interepret the response body as JSON. There are a number of libraries to help you do this:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Your answer is so wonderful, I am very contented and I highly appreciate, though I would like to know how to get the URL for the query.